# Powershell function reference and naming conventions

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-5.0, windows-scripting

I recently discovered that you can get powershell's functions by reference using the modifier `$function:`. But I noticed a strange problem...

By convention, POSH uses a `{Verb}-{Noun}` convention for function names, where `{Verb}` is part of [aproved POSH verb names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands). For instance: `Get-Member` or `Invoke-WebRequest`.

The thing is, that calling `$function:Get-Member`, for example, is not valid because of the hyphen; it works just fine if you declare a function like `ShowMessage` and calls: `$fn = $function:ShowMessage`. So I'd like to know if there's a way to escape this call.

**PS.:** I do know of another option, but is much much more verbose:

```
function Show-Message { Write-Host "Foo"; }
$fn = (Get-Item "function:Show-Message").ScriptBlock;
$fn.Invoke();
```

**Update:** Although @PetSerAl was very helpfull and explained the problem, I'll mark @Ansgar Wiechers's response as the answer because it's better documented.

Comment: `${function:Show-Message}`. Also `$function:` is not modifier. `function:` is a drive name.

Comment: Calling `${function:Get-Member}` is also not valid, as `Get-Member` is not a powershell function, but a cmdlet for compiled .net code from `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks, this solves it... By the way, do you have a reference about what you just told me? I was assuming `$function` was something related to "scope" like `$using` and `$global`.

Comment: I can not provide reference from memory. But you can easy [check it](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIU2hWkE9XV2hlkslTcFWQT1DHciASlqlcQWl5uaXpeoGBLsUZZalKsBkuFTySnNyFHRTCxWQVfullmMoVQhLLMpMTMpJVYhRqFHwLy3R9QNqRbbk/38A). Apart from `local`, `script`, `global`, `private`, `using` and `variable`, IIRC, anything else interpreted as drive name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function:` is a PSDrive, not a (scope)modifier. As for using it with variable-like notation (`$function:name`): the rules for variable names with special characters apply here as well.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-3.0#variable-names-that-include-special-characters):

> ### VARIABLE NAMES THAT INCLUDE SPECIAL CHARACTERS
>
> Variable names begin with a dollar sign. They can include alphanumeric characters and special characters. The length of the variable name is limited only by available memory.
>
> Whenever possible, variable names should include only alphanumeric characters and the underscore character (_).Variable names that include spaces and other special characters, are difficult to use and should be avoided.
>
> *To create or display a variable name that includes spaces or special characters, **enclose the variable name in braces.** This directs PowerShell to interpret the characters in the variable name literally.*

Your notation should thus look like this:

```
${function:Show-Message}
```

It can be invoked like this:

```
& ${function:Show-Message}
```